# StateInvariantError: GlyphView BadLocationException when using syntax highlighting and undo

Tags: java

I have a program which allows you to select text and add Html tags by pressing a key combination.

I'm trying to modify it so that highlighting is applied to the relevant portion of the document when any change takes place. However, under certain circumstances I'm getting this error: javax.swing.text.StateInvariantError: GlyphView: Stale view: javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Length must be positive.

The error can be seen in the following code. If you type in two lines of text, highlight the second one, press ALT+1 to add a tag, then press CTRL+Z to undo it, the program crashes.

There's a reference to a similar issue at https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1486098. However, the code posted is incomplete and I couldn't work out how to apply it to my problem. If someone could tell me where I am going wrong I would be very grateful!

```
package testprogram;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

import com.sun.java.swing.Painter;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class XemitTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private TextClass TextArea;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    String txtstr = "";

    public XemitTest() {

        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu("Menu");

        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        jMenuItem1.setText("<h1>");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                addInlineTags("<h1>", "</h1>");
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Z, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setText("Undo");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                actionUndo();
                if (TextArea.syntaxHighlighting)
                        highlightSyntax();
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Z, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        jMenuItem3.setText("Redo");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                actionRedo();
                if (TextArea.syntaxHighlighting)
                        highlightSyntax();
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar.add(jMenu);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);

        JEditorPane EditorPane = new TextClass();
        TextArea = (TextClass)EditorPane;

        final UndoableEditListener listener = new EditListener();
        TextArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(listener);
        TextArea.undo.setLimit(500);

        TextArea.addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (
                        e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB ||
                        e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ||
                        e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ||
                        e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE ||
                        e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DELETE
                    )
                        TextArea.keyValue = true;
                    else
                        TextArea.keyValue = false;
                }
            });

        getContentPane().add(TextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public class TextClass extends javax.swing.JTextPane {
            UndoManager undo = new UndoManager();
        public UndoableEditListener listener = null;
        CompoundEdit compoundEdit;
        boolean syntaxHighlighting = true, enableEdit = true, hasChanged = false, keyValue = false, lastKeyValue = false, forceCompoundEdit = false, editForced = false;
        int selstart = 0, selend = 0, strlen = 0, txtoffset = 0, txtlen = 0, txtoffsetChange = 0, txtlenChange = 0;
    }

    public class EditListener implements UndoableEditListener {
        @Override
        public void undoableEditHappened(final UndoableEditEvent e) {
            if (TextArea.enableEdit) {
                if (TextArea.compoundEdit == null) {
                    TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                    TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                }
                TextArea.txtoffsetChange = TextArea.getCaretPosition() - TextArea.txtoffset;
                TextArea.txtlenChange = TextArea.getDocument().getLength() - TextArea.txtlen;
                if (TextArea.forceCompoundEdit) {
                    if (!TextArea.editForced) {
                        if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
                            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
                        TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                        TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                        TextArea.editForced = true;
                    }
                    TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                }
                else {
                    if (TextArea.txtoffsetChange == TextArea.txtlenChange && Math.abs(TextArea.txtoffsetChange) == 1) {
                        if (TextArea.keyValue) {
                            if (TextArea.lastKeyValue) {
                                TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                            }
                            else {
                                if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
                                    TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
                                TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                                TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                                TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (!TextArea.lastKeyValue) {
                                TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                            }
                            else {
                                if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
                                    TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
                                TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                                TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                                TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
                        TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                        TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                        TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                    }
                }
                TextArea.lastKeyValue = TextArea.keyValue;
                TextArea.hasChanged = true;
                TextArea.txtoffset = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
                TextArea.txtlen = TextArea.getDocument().getLength();
                if (TextArea.syntaxHighlighting)
                        highlightSyntax();
            }
        }
    }

    private void highlightSyntax() {
        TextArea.enableEdit = false;
        try {
            int offset = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
            int line = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(offset);
            int start = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElement(line).getStartOffset();
            if (start < 0)
                start = 0;
                if (line > 0) {
                    start = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElement(line - 1).getStartOffset();
                    if (start < 0)
                        start = 0;
                }
                int end = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElement(line).getEndOffset();
                if (end > TextArea.getDocument().getLength())
                    end = TextArea.getDocument().getLength();
                int length = end - start;
                if (length > 0) {
                    StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) TextArea.getDocument();
                    Style styleDefault = document.addStyle("Default", null);
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(styleDefault, Color.BLACK);
                    Style styleHighlight = document.addStyle("Highlight", null);
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(styleHighlight, new Color(255, 0, 255));
                    String highlightstr = document.getText(start, length);
                    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("<[^<>\n]+>");
                    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(highlightstr);
                    document.setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, TextArea.getStyle("Default"), true);
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        document.setCharacterAttributes(start + matcher.start(), matcher.end() - matcher.start(), TextArea.getStyle("Highlight"), true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (BadLocationException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad Location Exception");
        }
        TextArea.enableEdit = true;
            TextArea.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private void actionUndo() {
        if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
        if (TextArea.undo.canUndo()) {
            try {
                TextArea.undo.undo();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action cannot be undone");
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No actions to undo");
        }
    }

    private void actionRedo() {
        if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
        if (TextArea.undo.canRedo()) {
            try {
                TextArea.undo.redo();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action cannot be redone");
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No actions to redo");
        }
    }

    private void addInlineTags(String starttag, String endtag) {
        TextArea.forceCompoundEdit = true;
        getSel();
        txtstr = starttag + txtstr + endtag;
        setSel();
        TextArea.forceCompoundEdit = false;
        TextArea.editForced = false;
    }

    private void getSel() {
        TextArea.selstart = TextArea.getSelectionStart();
        TextArea.selend = TextArea.getSelectionEnd();
        txtstr = (TextArea.getSelectedText() != null) ? TextArea.getSelectedText(): "";
    }

    private void setSel() {
        TextArea.replaceSelection(txtstr);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                XemitTest Xemit = new XemitTest();
                Xemit.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution to this problem...

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static TextClass TextArea;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    String txtstr = "";
    static Pattern re;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                test Xemit = new test();
                Xemit.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public test() {

    // Create GUI

        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu("Menu");

        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        jMenuItem1.setText("<h1>");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                addInlineTags("<h1>", "</h1>");
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Z, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setText("Undo");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                actionUndo();
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Z, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        jMenuItem3.setText("Redo");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                actionRedo();
            }
        });
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar.add(jMenu);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);

        JEditorPane EditorPane = new TextClass();
        TextArea = (TextClass)EditorPane;

        final Document document = TextArea.getDocument();
        final DocumentListener doclistener = new DocumentClass();
        document.addDocumentListener(doclistener);

        final UndoableEditListener editlistener = new EditClass();
        TextArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(editlistener);
        TextArea.undo.setLimit(500);

        TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
        TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);

        final KeyListener keylistener = new KeyClass();
        TextArea.addKeyListener(keylistener);

        final CaretListener caretlistener = new CaretClass();
        TextArea.addCaretListener(caretlistener);

        getContentPane().add(TextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

// Classes

public class TextClass extends javax.swing.JTextPane {
    UndoManager undo = new UndoManager();
        CompoundEdit compoundEdit;
        boolean enableedit = true, newedit = false, haschanged = false, newkeytype = false, lastkeytype = false, enablehighlight = true, highlight = false, fileopening = false;
        int strlen = 0, txtlen = 0, lasttxtlen = 0, caretpos = 0, lastcaretpos = 0, selstart = 0, selend = 0, highlightstart = 0, highlightend = 0, swap = 0;
        String filepath = "", filename = "", tempstr = "";

        public void selectAll() {
        selstart = 0;
        selend = getDocument().getLength();
        setSelectionStart(selstart);
        setSelectionEnd(selend);
        txtstr = getSelectedText();
        }

        public void cut() {
            this.newedit = true;
            super.cut();
        }

        public void paste() {
            this.newedit = true;
            txtstr = txtstr.replace("\t", "    ");
            super.paste();
        }
}

public class DocumentClass implements DocumentListener {
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    if (TextArea.enablehighlight) {
        TextArea.highlightstart = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
        HighlightClass.highlightSyntax();
        }
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (TextArea.enablehighlight) {
            TextArea.highlightstart = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
            HighlightClass.highlightSyntax();
        }
        }
    }

    public class EditClass implements UndoableEditListener {
        @Override
        public void undoableEditHappened(final UndoableEditEvent e) {
            if (TextArea.enableedit) {
                if (! TextArea.highlight) {
                    if (TextArea.newedit) {
                        if (TextArea.compoundEdit.isInProgress())
                            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
                        TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                        TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                    } else if (! TextArea.compoundEdit.isInProgress()) {
                        TextArea.compoundEdit = new CompoundEdit();
                        TextArea.undo.addEdit(TextArea.compoundEdit);
                    }
                TextArea.haschanged = true;
                }
                TextArea.compoundEdit.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                TextArea.newedit = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class KeyClass implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            TextArea.caretpos = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
            if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB ||
                e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ||
                e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ||
                e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE ||
                e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
                TextArea.newkeytype = true;
            } else {
                TextArea.newkeytype = false;
            }
            if (TextArea.newkeytype != TextArea.lastkeytype || Math.abs(TextArea.caretpos - TextArea.lastcaretpos) > 1)
                TextArea.newedit = true;
            TextArea.lastkeytype = TextArea.newkeytype;
            TextArea.lastcaretpos = TextArea.caretpos;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public class CaretClass implements CaretListener {
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            TextArea.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public static class HighlightClass extends DefaultStyledDocument {
        public static void highlightSyntax() {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                TextArea.highlight = true;
                if (! TextArea.fileopening)
                    TextArea.highlightend = TextArea.getCaretPosition();
                if (TextArea.highlightstart > TextArea.highlightend) {
                    TextArea.swap = TextArea.highlightend;
                    TextArea.highlightstart = TextArea.highlightend;
                    TextArea.highlightend = TextArea.swap;
                }
                    int startpos = TextArea.highlightstart;
                    int endpos = TextArea.highlightend;
                    int startline = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(startpos);
                    int start = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElement(startline).getStartOffset();
                    int endline = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(endpos);
                    int end = TextArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElement(endline).getEndOffset();
                    int length = Math.abs(end - start);
                    try {
                        StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) TextArea.getDocument();
                        Style styleDefault = document.addStyle("Default", null);
                        StyleConstants.setForeground(styleDefault, new Color(0, 0, 0));
                        document.setCharacterAttributes(start, length, TextArea.getStyle("Default"), true);
                        Style styleHighlight = document.addStyle("Highlight", null);
                        StyleConstants.setForeground(styleHighlight, new Color(255, 0, 255));
                        String highlightstr = document.getText(start, length);
        try {
            re = Pattern.compile("<[a-z/][^<>\n]*>");
            } catch(PatternSyntaxException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search string cannot be compiled.");
                return;
                }
                Matcher matcher = re.matcher(highlightstr);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                document.setCharacterAttributes(start + matcher.start(), matcher.end() - matcher.start(), TextArea.getStyle("Highlight"), true);
                }
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                }
                TextArea.fileopening = false;
                TextArea.highlight = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Methods

    private void actionUndo() {
        if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
        if (TextArea.undo.canUndo()) {
            try {
                TextArea.undo.undo();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action cannot be undone");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No actions to undo");
        }
    }

    private void actionRedo() {
        if (TextArea.compoundEdit != null)
            TextArea.compoundEdit.end();
        if (TextArea.undo.canRedo()) {
            try {
                TextArea.undo.redo();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action cannot be redone");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No actions to redo");
        }
    }

    private void addInlineTags(String starttag, String endtag) {
        getSel();
        if (txtstr.matches("\\A\\s*\\Z")) {
            txtstr = starttag + endtag;
            setSel();
        } else {
            txtstr = txtstr
                .replaceAll("\\A(\\s*)(\\S)", "$1" + starttag + "$2")
                .replaceAll("(\\S)(\\s*)\\Z", "$1" + endtag + "$2");
            setSel();
        }
    }

    private void getSel() {
        TextArea.selstart = TextArea.getSelectionStart();
        TextArea.selend = TextArea.getSelectionEnd();
        txtstr = (TextArea.getSelectedText() != null) ? TextArea.getSelectedText(): "";
        TextArea.strlen = txtstr.length();
    }

    private void setSel() {
        TextArea.selstart = TextArea.getSelectionStart();
        TextArea.selend = TextArea.selstart + txtstr.length();
        TextArea.newedit = true;
        TextArea.replaceSelection(txtstr);
    }
}
```